# Solr 3.5 indexing taking very long

Tags: solr

We recently migrated from solr3.1 to solr3.5,  we have one master and one slave configured. The master has two cores,

```
1) Core1 – 44555972 documents
2) Core2 – 29419244 documents
```

We commit every 5000 documents, but lately the commit is taking very long 15 minutes plus in some cases. What could have caused this, I have checked the logs and the only warning i can see is,

> “WARNING: Use of deprecated update request parameter update.processor detected. Please use the new parameter update.chain instead, as support for update.processor will be removed in a later version.”

**Memory details:**

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms6g -Xmx36g -XX:MaxPermSize=5g"

**Solr Config:**

```
<useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
<mergeFactor>10</mergeFactor>
<ramBufferSizeMB>32</ramBufferSizeMB>
<!-- <maxBufferedDocs>1000</maxBufferedDocs> -->
<maxFieldLength>10000</maxFieldLength>
<writeLockTimeout>1000</writeLockTimeout>
<commitLockTimeout>10000</commitLockTimeout>
```

Also noticed, that top command show almost 350GB of Virtual memory usage.

What could be causing this, as everything was running fine a few days back?

Comment: Are you optimizing on every commit? And that is a very large amount of memory for the JVM, consider a much smaller heap, perhaps 4G or 8G. You might be spending minutes in a GC.

Comment: No we are not optimizing every commit, we do it once day.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a large search warming query?  Our commits take upto 2 mins because of search warming in place.  Wondering if that is the case.

The large virtual memory usage would explain this.